# Toggle DIV on LABEL Click Inside a repeater control in ASP.Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, html, show

I have `repeater control` for which am binding the data from DB. This repeater has `LABEL(ID=EmpName)` control in a separate DIV. On `mouseover` event of this `LABEL` i have to `show/hide` another DIV which has `LABEL` control to show the some values.

Currently am able to do this but I have used click event and when i click any row in the repeater control `(LABEL(ID=EmpName))` all the DIV's are shown.

Below i have given the source.

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="MyCreditRep" OnItemDataBound="MyCreditRep_ItemDataBound"
    OnItemCommand="MyCreditRep_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="productlist">
            <div>
                <div class="producthead" style="float: left;">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" style="height: 50px">
                                <%--        <p>Test</p>--%>
                                <p id="P1" class="flip">
                                    <asp:Label ID="ProductLbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Product_Name") %>' class="panel"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            </p>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="clearboth">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ProductPointsDiv" runat="server" class="panel">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left: 75px" class="product_point_body">
                        <asp:Label ID="ProductPointLbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Point_Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

java script function:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".flip").click(function() {
                    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
                });
            });
   </script>
```

css:

```
div.panel, p.flip
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
div.panel
{
    height: 80px;
    display: none;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: why dont u use collapsable panel in ajax 3.5 ... y do u make ur problem complicated

Comment: Hi Madhu, can you give me some examples to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Untitled Page


        
                // Based on: http://blogs.msdn.com/phaniraj/archive/2007/06/20/how-to-perform-operations-on-all-instances-of-a-ajax-control-extender-on-a-page.aspx

```
            // Function To Collapse all CollapsiblePanels on a page , if not already collapsed, except the one specified.
            function collapseAllOtherCollapsiblePanels(id) {
                    // Loop through all the Behaviors Present in the Page
                    var allBehaviors = Sys.Application.getComponents() ;
                    var currentBehavior = null;
                    for( var loopIndex = 0 ; loopIndex < allBehaviors.length; loopIndex++ ) {
                            currentBehavior = allBehaviors[loopIndex];
                            // If its of type CollapsiblePanelBehavior
                            if( currentBehavior.get_name() === "CollapsiblePanelBehavior" ) {
                                    // Check that the current panel is not the panel that's expanding
                                    if (currentBehavior.get_id() != id) {
                                            // Check if the Panel is Collapsed
                                            if( !currentBehavior.get_Collapsed() ) {
                                                    // If not collapsed , collapse the Panel.
                                                    currentBehavior.collapsePanel();
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                    return false;
            }
    </script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>              
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table>
                            <thead>
                                    <th>Stuff</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                            <td>
                                    <%# Eval("Subject")%>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="ShowHideButton" runat="server" Text="Show Time" 
                                            OnClientClick="collapseAllOtherCollapsiblePanels(this.id);"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:Panel ID="TimePanel" runat="server">
                                            <%# Eval("StartTime", "{0:d}")%> - <%# Eval("EndTime", "{0:d}")%>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsePanel1" runat="server" SuppressPostBack="true" 
                                            CollapseControlID="ShowHideButton" Collapsed="true" CollapsedText="Show Time" 
                                            ExpandControlID="ShowHideButton" ExpandedText="Hide Time" TargetControlID="TimePanel">
                                    </ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString1 %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [Subject], [StartTime], [EndTime] FROM [DateTest]">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Madhu,I have n number of LABEL and n (same number as LABEL) number DIV added inside the repeater at run time (1st LABEL, then 1st DIV, 2nd LABEL then 2nd DIV and so on). Now doing mouseover event for the each LABEL control I have to display only the DIV next to the LABEL control.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the perfect example for your requirement

https://web.archive.org/web/20210619180348/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091504-1.aspx and [live example](https://web.archive.org/web/20171229131539/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/demos/CollapsibleRepeater.aspx)  u can have a look and proceed further

i hope this will help !!!